# How to change the Date Format in Chart.js?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am confused about how to change my Date Format in Chart.js.
I grabbed my data from the MySQL database one of my columns is called "StartD"

> [{"RECORD_NO":217,"Cost":4971,"StartD":"5/8/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":216,"Cost":1814,"StartD":"4/8/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":215,"Cost":3335,"StartD":"3/8/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":214,"Cost":1886,"StartD":"2/8/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":213,"Cost":1274,"StartD":"1/8/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":212,"Cost":2238,"StartD":"31/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":211,"Cost":1819,"StartD":"30/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":210,"Cost":1021,"StartD":"29/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":209,"Cost":2564,"StartD":"28/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":208,"Cost":4534,"StartD":"27/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":207,"Cost":4187,"StartD":"26/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":206,"Cost":2337,"StartD":"25/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":205,"Cost":4778,"StartD":"24/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":204,"Cost":3215,"StartD":"23/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":203,"Cost":4469,"StartD":"22/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":202,"Cost":1883,"StartD":"21/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":201,"Cost":1097,"StartD":"20/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":200,"Cost":2918,"StartD":"19/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":199,"Cost":4956,"StartD":"18/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":198,"Cost":1565,"StartD":"17/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":197,"Cost":4425,"StartD":"16/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":196,"Cost":2277,"StartD":"15/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":195,"Cost":3866,"StartD":"14/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":194,"Cost":1546,"StartD":"13/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":193,"Cost":563,"StartD":"12/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":192,"Cost":576,"StartD":"11/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":191,"Cost":731,"StartD":"10/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":190,"Cost":2850,"StartD":"9/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":189,"Cost":1154,"StartD":"8/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":188,"Cost":4447,"StartD":"7/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":187,"Cost":3476,"StartD":"6/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":186,"Cost":1047,"StartD":"5/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":185,"Cost":1049,"StartD":"4/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":184,"Cost":1566,"StartD":"3/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":183,"Cost":700,"StartD":"2/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":182,"Cost":4728,"StartD":"1/7/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":181,"Cost":4549,"StartD":"30/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":180,"Cost":1155,"StartD":"29/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":179,"Cost":2148,"StartD":"28/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":178,"Cost":4934,"StartD":"27/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":177,"Cost":4353,"StartD":"26/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":176,"Cost":2546,"StartD":"25/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":175,"Cost":1239,"StartD":"24/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":174,"Cost":1724,"StartD":"23/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":173,"Cost":769,"StartD":"22/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":172,"Cost":670,"StartD":"21/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":171,"Cost":4634,"StartD":"20/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":170,"Cost":2742,"StartD":"19/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":169,"Cost":4797,"StartD":"18/6/2022"},{"RECORD_NO":168,"Cost":3317,"StartD":"17/6/2022"}]

I put it into my BarChar.js file and it recognized the data.

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react'
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js'
import {
  Bar
} from "react-chartjs-2"
// Radar, Doughnut, Polar, Pie
import axios from 'axios';


ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend
);


function BarChart() {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    datasets: [],
  });

  const Chart = () => {
    let Cost = [];
    let No = [];

    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/TranscationRecord/Cost")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        for (const dataObj of res.data) {
          Cost.push(parseInt(dataObj.Cost));
          No.push(parseInt(dataObj.StartD));
        }
        setChartData({
          labels: No,
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Daily Cost',
            data: Cost,
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            options: {
              scales: {
                x: {
                  type: 'time',
                  time: {
                    unit: 'date',
                    parser: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                  }
                },
                y: {
                  beginAtZero: true
                }
              }

            }

          }]
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    Chart();
  }, []);

  return ( <
    div className = "App" >
    <
    h1 > Bar Chart < /h1> <
    div >
    <
    Bar data = {
      chartData
    }
    /> < /
    div > <
    /div>  
  )
}
export default BarChart;
```

The result
[image: The result]

It can only present the Day but not the format of "DD/MM"
Is that a way to solve the problem?

Comment: if truly MySQL than please tag MySQL and not SQL Server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try `displayFormats`:

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[Chart.js Time Display Formats](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats)

Answer (score 0):

The x-axis of your bar chart is currently a [category axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html#category-axis) instead of a [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-cartesian-axis). The reason is that `options` is misplaced, it should not be defined inside the `dataset` but follow the [top level structure](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/#configuration-object-structure) of the Chart.js configuration.

With `react-chartjs-2`, you would define `options` as a separate object and provide it as follows:

```
<Bar data={data} options={options} />
```

Once this is is corrected, the display format can be defined according to the Chart.js documentation [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats).

Please also consider that the time scale requires both, [a date library and a corresponding adapter](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters) to be present.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop like below

```
for (const dataObj of res.data) {
      Cost.push(parseInt(dataObj.Cost));
      const date = new Date(dataObj.StartD);
      No.push(date->toLocaleDateString('en-us',{month:"2-digit", day:"2-digit"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out the answer. Thanks for helping. I take [@terinao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13304061/terinao)'s code for references.

Changing the code like this can solve the problem.

```
 axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/TranscationRecord/Cost")
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        for(const dataObj of res.data){
            Cost.push(parseInt(dataObj.Cost));
            const d = new Date(dataObj.StartD);
            No.push(d.toLocaleDateString('en-us',{day:"2-digit",month:"2-digit" }));
        }
```

The result be like:
(I change the colour into blue but they are the same datasets)
[The bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nisvt.png)